# What is the default font for tooltips in browsers?

Tags: html, browser, fonts

I know the browser decides what its tooltips (via HTMl title attribute) look like and that it can't be changed except maybe with some browser settings. In my case Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome and Safari all used the same font, which looked quite similar to Segoe UI. Where do they draw that from?
I need to simulate the look of the tooltips and therefore would need to know which font is used.

Comment: I think that you can check the font used in the body, so for chrome should be segoe UI, but i'm not 100% sure

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. The font set for the HTML body tag doesn't influence what the tooltips look like, they always look the same.

Comment: This one can help a bit maybe? http://superuser.com/questions/138419/what-font-does-google-chrome-address-bar-use - It says for the address bar, but i tried the tooltips and in my case (windows 8.1) the font in the tooltip is segoe UI, so i think it is true for all the brower elements and not just for the address bar

Comment: Seems you're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer this, as pointed out in in this superuser question: https://superuser.com/questions/138419/what-font-does-google-chrome-address-bar-use

The system's interface font will be used:

- Windows XP: Tahoma
- Vista and 7: Segoe UI
- GNOME Shell: Cantarell
- Mac OS X: Lucida Grande

Comment: What is the default font for current version of Windows and other OS?

Comment: Thank you. Windows 10 also uses Segoe UI. Font size 18.